# How can I apply an anonymous traversal to a graph in Gremlin?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I've got a (generated) anonymous gremlin traversal. I know for a fact that:

- it contains start steps (`.V()` / `.E()`)
- it has been created exclusively using anonmous traversal (the `__` class)

Now, I want to evaluate the traversal on my real graph. How exactly do I do this in the Gremlin 3.x API?

I already tried:

```java
anonymousTraversal.asAdmin().setGraph(myGraph);
var result = anonymousTraversal.toList();
```

... but that didn't produce any data. I also tried the traversal union trick:

```java
myGraph.traversal().inject(0).union(anonymousTraversal)
```

This produced the expected result, but I feel that this is a bit overkill for the task at hand. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need to build the query using an Anonymous Traversal instead of off of a Graph Traversal Source object?

If you have a Graph Traversal Source object, you can do something like:

```
query = g.V()

query = query.has('name','Bob')

query = query.out('friendsWith')
```

And then the query only gets executed when you add the terminal step:

```
results = query.toList()
```

Comment: Yes, there is. The gremlin is generated, and the traversal generation doesn't know from the get-go which gremlin will end up as the "root traversal" and which ones will be "sub traversals". Since a gremlin can only be turned into a sub-traversal if it uses the anonymous traversal as starts, we use them for *all* our traversals. Only at the very end, when the traversal generation is done, we bind the traversal which ended up as the root traversal to our actual graph.